# p:autocomplete not working inside jquery steps form wizard

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using jquery steps as a form wizard and I need to implement the autocomplete of primefaces inside the form wizard, but the autocomplete is not working inside the wizard form, when I put the autocomplete out of the form, it works, this is the code that I use

```
 <h:form id="accomplishment-form" styleClass="wizard-big">
    ***********************some code*****************************************
    <p:autoComplete disabled="#{(awardActivity.award.awardProof != null or awardActivity.award.awardProof != '') and (awardActivity.award.certificationApproved==0 or awardActivity.award.certificationApproved==1)}" value="#{awardActivity.award.country.name}" forceSelection="false"
    completeMethod="#{candidateController.autocompleteResidence}"
    placeholder="Search Country">
    <p:ajax update="accomplishment-form" event="itemSelect" process="@this"></p:ajax>
    </p:autoComplete>
     ********************some code********************************
    </h:form>
```

this is the jquery steps wizard

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#wizard").steps();
        $("#accomplishment-form").steps({
            bodyTag: "fieldset",
            onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
            {
                // Always allow going backward even if the current step contains invalid fields!
                if (currentIndex > newIndex)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                // Forbid suppressing "Warning" step if the user is to young
                if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age").val()) < 18)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var form = $(this);

                // Clean up if user went backward before
                if (currentIndex < newIndex)
                {
                    // To remove error styles
                    $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error", form).remove();
                    $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error", form).removeClass("error");
                }

                // Disable validation on fields that are disabled or hidden.
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";

                // Start validation; Prevent going forward if false
                return form.valid();
            },
            onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
            {
                // Suppress (skip) "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
                if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age").val()) >= 18)
                {
                    $(this).steps("next");
                }

                // Suppress (skip) "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
                if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
                {
                    $(this).steps("previous");
                }
            },
            onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
            {
                var form = $(this);

                // Disable validation on fields that are disabled.
                // At this point it's recommended to do an overall check (mean ignoring only disabled fields)
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";

                // Start validation; Prevent form submission if false
                return form.valid();
            },
            onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
            {
                var form = $(this);

                // Submit form input
                form.submit();
            }
        }).validate({
                    errorPlacement: function (error, element)
                    {
                        element.before(error);
                    },
                    rules: {
                        confirm: {
                            equalTo: "#password"
                        }
                    }
                });

   });
```